# Paperclip options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the gem 'paperclip' in my rails project and am smashing my head on the desk trying to figure out if I can get paperclip to stop uploading multiple copies of the same picture.

Basically, I have a sunglass object (product) that is made up of different pieces - lens, frame, temple, and photo (assume product_params). I am using paperclip for the photo upload but when I run the code below it also uploads the image 'quantity' times.

I understand that's how it's written, but is there a way to upload just 1 photo, and use that same filepath for the rest of the 'quantity' products? More importantly can I do it with paperclip or is there another method that would work?

```
if quantity > 0
  quantity.times do
    @product = Product.create(product_params)
  end
else
    @product = Product.create(product_params)
end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458067/rails-preventing-duplicate-photo-uploads-with-paperclip

Comment: What is the reasoning behind creating multiple `Product` records, with the same params for each? It seems like a lot of duplicated information that could maybe be avoided by taking another approach rather than trying to bend Paperclip to fit this approach. Perhaps create just one `Product` and have `quantity` be a column in the `products` table instead of creating 'quantity' products?

Comment: You're the (insert large number)th person to ask that @james246 .. It's getting to the point where I'm about to scrap the whole project and start over because having a quantity column makes more sense than having each product have it's own object record. It was initially so that that each product would be able to be tracked individually for warranty purposes, but it's irrelevant now.

Comment: if you want to keep the objects separate - what about creating another model called Type which describes a product and keeps a picture per type. Then every Product belongs to a Type, therefore having a picture and basic information but still the ability to keep the different units apart?